# Imported Android Project into Eclipse but it's not recognized

Tags: android, eclipse, import

I'm trying to import the Android tictactoe project [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-endpoints-tictactoe-android) into Eclipse to try out Google Cloud SQL [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/consume_android).

I can import the project but Eclipse doesn't recognize this as an Android project.  I can edit the build path or figure out how to make Eclipse recognize it.  Yes, I have other working projects in this workspace.

[image: Build Path]

[image: Project Properties]

Can anyone tell me what is wrong?

Comment: The setup instructions are pretty detailed. If you have followed every piece of instruction to the word and still unable to get it running, you should probably raise an issue at GitHub. This seems a bit stupid to ask...but you did import it as an Android project right? (If it is, in fact, an Android project, that is)

Comment: I disagree that they are detailed.  For example, the project points you to the google-api-java-client for some libraries but one of the libraries is not at that location (yes I submitted an issue on that one).

And yes, I have tried importing as an Android project and as a general project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it was just a random Eclipse issue.  I tried reimporting later several times and it worked.